# No Unicode in `__all__` for a package's `__init__`?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, python-import

Are Unicode literals not allowed in `__all__` in Python 2.7.5? I've got an `__init__.py` file with `from __future__ import unicode_literals` at the top, along with coding utf-8. (There are also some unicode strings in it, hence the future import.)

To ensure that only some of the modules are visible when imported using `from mypackage import *`, I've added my class to `__all__`. But I get ``` TypeError: Item in ``from list'' not a string ```. Why is that? Bug?

However, when I cast the class name to str in `__all__`, it works just fine.
*[ It also works when I specify `from mypackage import SomeClass` in run.py below...since the items in `__all__` are not processed. ]*

---

mypackage/somemodule.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

class SomeClass(object):
    pass
```

mypackage/ `__init__`.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from .somemodule import SomeClass

__all__ = ['SomeClass']
```

run.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from mypackage import *

print('yay')
```

To avoid the error, I change the 'all' declaration to:

```
__all__ = [str('SomeClass')] #pylint: disable=invalid-all-object
```

which, of course, pylint complains about.

My other option is to **not** import `unicode_literals` and explicitly cast all the strings in init to unicode with `u'uni string'`.

Comment: Actually, it is a [bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue21720).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, unicode values are not allowed in `__all__`, because in Python 2 names are strings, not unicode values.

Your indeed have to encode all strings in `__all__` or not use unicode literals. You could do so as a separate step:

```
__all__ = ['SomeClass']
__all__ = [n.encode('ascii') for n in __all__]
```

In Python 3, variable names are unicode values too, so there `__all__` is *expected* to have unicode strings.

Comment: But in Python 3.x, if all strings are default Unicode, how does that not give an error? The names being sourced from the `__all__` list are still from unicode strings and not ascii strings (even though in both cases, only ascii chars are used) ?

Comment: @aneroid: In Python 3, python *names* are unicode too. In Python 2, names can only use ASCII, in Python 3 that restriction is lifted.

Comment: Okay, that I did not know. Makes sense then.